# Redirect to another website with sweetalert2 and GET information

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, sweetalert2

So I want to redirect using sweetalert2 to, say deleting.php with the ?ID= something. How do I put in the something? Here's my code. The first one is in php echo html so that I can put in everything from the sql database.

```
echo'
<td style="text-align: center;"> <div class="btn-group dropup">
<button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Action
</button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="edit_form.php?ID='.$operatives['ID'].'">Edit</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item red" onclick="oof("'.$operatives['ID'].'")" href="#">Purge</a>
   </div>
</div> </td>'
```

And this is the sweetalert2 code

```
<script>
function oof(id){
    var MyId = id;
    Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You will be purging this person's account.",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
  cancelButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, purge account'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    window.location = "deleting.php?ID="+MyId;
  }
})
}
</script>
```

Let's say the ID is 4, if possible, I'd like it so it could redirect to deleting.php?ID=4. Thank you!

Also is it possible to activate sweetalert2 from GET information and how?

Comment: your question is not clear, what you exactly want?

Comment: I want to pass information to the function for sweetalert from the php so that it can use that to redirect me to another site with the ?id=something info

Comment: Concatenating strings in JavaScript is done with a `+` and not with a `.`. So your redirect has to look like `window.location = "deleting.php?ID=" + id;`. That 's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than in PHP concatenating strings in JavaScript is not done with a dot. You have to use a `+` character to concatenate. Therefor your code has to look like the following example;

```
window.location = "deleting.php?ID=" + id;
```

Activating SweetAlert as a JavaScript library by a GET parameter is possible. Just use the native `URLSearchParams` object for this.

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');

if (myParam) {
    // initialize here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The + worked! If you don't mind me asking though, the sweetalert2 doesn't seem to run when I click it now, when I added parameters to the function, even when I added var MyId. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!